# Extracting int array from compiled C++ code

Tags: c++, security

Is it possible for an attacker to get integer arrays from your compiled code?

Like how the attacker can get strings from your code using the `strings` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A quick example with `main.c`:

```
int main(void) {
        int vars[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
}
```

Then `gcc -O0 main.c -o main` to disable optimization so our unused array isn't removed. Then if you simply disassemble it:

```
0000000000400474 <main>:
  400474:       55                      push   %rbp
  400475:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400478:       c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
  40047f:       c7 45 e4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x1c(%rbp)
  400486:       c7 45 e8 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,-0x18(%rbp)
  40048d:       c7 45 ec 03 00 00 00    movl   $0x3,-0x14(%rbp)
  400494:       c7 45 f0 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,-0x10(%rbp)
  40049b:       c7 45 f4 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0xc(%rbp)
  4004a2:       c7 45 f8 06 00 00 00    movl   $0x6,-0x8(%rbp)
  4004a9:       c7 45 fc 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,-0x4(%rbp)
```

It makes logical sense, if you have data in your code and your program uses it, then the data must exist somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. So if you declare variable one after the other will they too be placed in contiguous memory?

Comment: Basically, yes. Compiler optimizations may change how it all looks so it isn't as simple as int[4] declared after int[4] will result in the same above, but the jist of it all is any information you put into your code and send to someone should be considered 'public' information. The client is always an untrusted user. You can make it much more difficult to do this than the above example with things like obfuscation and packing, but it all falls within the same concept. The data will be there, and the data can be extracted.

Comment: Thanks again :) it really helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I recommend you to open a executable file after compiled with notepad++ or notepad, and maybe you see something as:

[image: .exe file open with notepad++, look to Hello world statement]

But why this is so simple with strings and not with vectors? Because strings are usually just made by alfphanumeric letters and so on, just seen them inside of binary files we found tham, an array of int will be inside of your code as raw data but eye seen them is hard since they are not (obligatorily) printed characters, but if you use a disassembling program it is as easy to find strings as other arrays.